# What does the below SQL injection indicate?

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection

What is the meaning of this command in SQL ?

```
php?que_id
=-1/**/UNION/**/
ALL/**/SELECT
```

What does `/**/?` indicate here?

Comment: @paj28 Write it as an answer and I'll +1

Answer (score 3):

This is an empty SQL comment, and is treated the same as a space.

This trick can be used to get around filters that strip out spaces. It may also be introduced to bypass a WAF or IDS.

Comment: Can it attack the database and lead to high risk ?

Comment: @user45475 It depends on your PHP app. If coded securely you're ok. But if there's an SQL injection vulnerability in that parameter, then yes, this absolutely can attack the database, and most likely extract all the data.